# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I know this type of question as probably been asked a couple of times, but they all have something to do with laravel, in my case this is vanilla php with no framework.

I have a form that that will collect form from users and save it into the database as it should, but i keep getting this error about MYSQL `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`. Here is my database config file and the file that includes it:

```php
// Database config 
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'admin';
$password = '123456';
$db_name = 'nairobi';

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name;
$options = [ 
  PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
];

    // Create a new PDO instance 
    try {
      $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
      die();
    }

?>
```

```php
<?php 
require "./library/Database.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO TABLE members(first_name, last_name, email) 
  VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email)';
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt_value = [
    ':first_name' => $first_name, 
    ':last_name' => $last_name, 
    ':email'=>$email
  ];
  $stmt->execute($stmt_value);
}


?>
```

Yes, I know the script that process the form is not secure.

Also, I get the following error when I access the page

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/html/library/Database.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/library/Database.php on line 19
```

If needed, this is the sql I have gone with

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members(
  member_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  reference_code INT NOT NULL
);
```

This entire project is also inside a docker container, here is the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  php:
    container_name: nairobi_php
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - './src:/var/www/html'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80

  mysql:
    container_name: nairobi_mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: CUeHpADRmZCtnTFGctxp
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nairobi
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: are you sure that "./library/Database.php"; exists at that place?

Comment: did you change codes in database.php with the codes in answer ? and did you make sure if your port is correct like I mentioned in answer ? and are you sure there is not anything else in database.php ? line 19 is a } in my codes

Comment: This what the source code looks like on my [end](https://imgur.com/KNVQuiv)

Comment: See answer I updated! and would you please take a screen shot and add some where else please I dont see anything from imgur.com

Comment: Here is the update link of the source code on my [end](https://imgur.com/mRRZrmO)

Comment: Change your table with mine in answer! you have syntax errors and no limit for int columns! and what is this `reference_code INT NOT NULL` what you are going to insert in that column ?

Comment: I change my table with yours, still the same error, I even tried rebuilding my docker container, but still the same problem.

Comment: First change all your codes to mine and than See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075065/using-docker-i-get-the-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory I tested every step of my codes works fine. Note I am not using docker

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved the problem, thanks @Dlk for your help.

The cause of the problem was because in `database.php`, I was referring to the host for mysql as `localhost` instead of the name of the MYSQL service in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Hence `database.php` file should look like so :

```php
<?php

$host = 'nairobi_mysql'; // Must be the service name of the database in `docker-compose.yml`
$db_name = 'nairobi';
$user = 'admin';
$pass = '123456';
$charset = 'utf8mb4'; // Always set charset for database
$port = '3306'; 

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

?>
```

which correlates with my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  php:
    container_name: nairobi_php
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - './src:/var/www/html'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80

  mysql:
    container_name: nairobi_mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: CUeHpADRmZCtnTFGctxp
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nairobi
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: Nice glad you solved! I mentioned that in comment you probably didnt see *Can you change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or your ip if you have one* ip -> your service name

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your connection like this: replace codes in Database.php with the following codes and read comments in codes.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'nairobi';
$user = 'admin';
$pass = '123456';
$charset = 'utf8mb4'; // Always set charset for database
$port = '3308'; //Your port can be 3306 or 3307

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Now your codes! you are using prepare statements which makes your codes safe enough.
Check if url to `Database.php` file is correct and change yours to this

```
require_once "./library/Database.php";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
      $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $reference_code = $_POST['reference_code'];
    //You have a `TABLE` name call members so you dont need `TABLE` its causing problem
    //Your query should look like this
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO members (first_name, last_name, email, reference_code) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :reference_code)';
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$first_name, $last_name, $email, $reference_code]);
    //I removed array here which you dont need, you can directly add fields in execute.
      $stmt->closeCursor();
    //Use `closeCursor()` to free your connection instead unset or close.
    }
```

**Final** 
make sure you created a database.
make sure you created a table call members in database.

if you have done that all, your codes will work without any problem.

HTML form should look like this, you need to add multi encrypt into form if you want to upload images.

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
  <div class="container">first_name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first_name" name="first_name" required>

    <label for="last_name"><b>last_name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last_name" name="last_name" required>

    <label for="email"><b>email</b></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>

    <label for="reference_code"><b>reference_code</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter reference_code" name="reference_code" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Datatable should look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `member_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reference_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate your help, but now I have run into another snag. Here is the error I got [here](https://imgur.com/3N7UQJm). If it also helps this is inside a docker container

Comment: Check url you added nothing in it, edit your question and add error at the bottom of it. and check if path of  "./library/Database.php"; is  correct

Comment: Can you change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or your ip if you have one. see connection with docker https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host