# PHP file wont connect to the sql database, it says error #1045 but the values on the code are right

Tags: php, sql, wamp

I tried connecting my PHP file to MySQli database but when i ran the code it displays [image]

But when i logon to phpmyadmin it works fine no errors i can login to my account with no problems

**Credentials in the database:**
[image]

**Connection Code:**

```php
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','sotomango', '1234', 'mysql');

    if(!$con) {

        echo 'noooo';

    }

?>
```

I double checked the database usernames, passwords, and privileges. Everything seems in place and correct, but the php file wont allow me to connect to the database.

Comment: but does the user have access to the database? right credentials != right permissions

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR sotomango@localhost` show?

Comment: @treyBake yes i gave all permissions to the user

Comment: @Barmar the grants show ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sotomango'@'localh...```

Comment: @AlexMA no not really, i tried that already yet still i cant login to the database

Comment: @Cd_Codes It's almost certainly either a credentials problem or a privileges problem. And there are many answers on the site already answering this question.

Comment: @AlexMA but why is it possible that i can login with phpadmin no problem and i have all my privileges?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca solve your problem?

Comment: Nope not really @AlexMA. I flushed the privileges after i reloaded them

Comment: Did you try using the ip instead of locahost?

Comment: @AlexMA yes still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dharman had a nice post but I couldnt find it.

Try this for debug :

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

    if (!$con) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
  echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is 
  great." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($con);
```

[mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

if its a new instalation or new upgrade, You need to include your port into connection, mariadb comes as default port so, when you try to connect mysql its redirecting to mariadb.

you need to include your correct port into connection it might be 3306, 3307 or 3308, and **use ip instead of localhost**.

your final codes should look like this :

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = '3308';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $port, $db);
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, $charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: actually you could do `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3308","sotomango", "1234",'mysql');`

Comment: Yes I could and then your comon sence or dharman would say no dlk :) glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

For The People Wondering

I solved this by just adding a port to the host name like `localhost:3308`

Comment: Because the ***default*** MySQL Port is `3306`, your port of `3308` is **REQUIRED** because it is not the default. This is why this is your issue and this should be outlined for others reading this question. Glad you found the answer.