# mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to create login system for my school project, but I run into a problem.
When I'm trying to connect to database it always throw error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'userverification'

It will pass only when I use databases which were created with installation of phpMyAdmin.

Code Im using for connecting is:

```
<?php

        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASS', '');
        define('DB_NAME', 'userverification');


        $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die('Database error: . $conn->connect_error');
        }
?>
```

Comment: then it means there is no database having those parameters.

Comment: This error tells you that your *DBMS* has no Database named *userverification*. The DB doesn't have to be created explicitly through phpmyadmin, but it must be somehow created. It seems to me that you are asking following question _Why can't i connect to a non existing database_ which sounds silly, you can't because the Database does not exist.

Comment: Does `userverification` is database name, not a table name in some database? check that `SHOW DATABASES` lists it (execute in phpMyAdmin or in console client)...

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I thought that I can create database in phpmyadmin and than write code and it will connect. This is what I did, I created database in phpmyadmin. I dont know what Im doing wrong then.

Comment: @Akina It is database name. I did that command and `userverification` is in the list.

Comment: This question has tons of answers in this site, This is one of your answer I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655066/12232340 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813485/12232340

Comment: @Dlk Oh my god, thanks a lot for these answers. I wasnt able to to find the right words to search for these. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChessMan Glad I helped! You could upvote that answers :)