# Mysqli_connect() not working on live server

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having strange problem on the live server , mysqli_connect() does not working on the live server , although when I am using new mysqli() it is working on the live server , in my case I cannot use the new mysqli() OOP paradigm. I want to do it by mysqli_connect() , I have checked the php.ini file on the server it shows that I can use mysqli_connect()

**this is my connection object with mysqli_connect();**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
```

this is not working

**although when i am using the same credentials with new mysqli()**

```
$conn= new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxxx");
```

this piece of code is working..

**Any help would be appreciated I want to execute my connection with mysqli_connect()**

I am getting this error

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):
```

Comment: What error does it give you? You may need to explicitly check for [mysqli_connect_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Comment: @aynber when I added the command mentioned in the link you have given inside the comment nothing shows up..

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Not working in what way? If `$conn` is false, you really should be getting an error.

Comment: showing what ever is mentioned inside the die() function

Comment: Have you checked the server's error logs?

Comment: This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655066/12232340

Comment: I am getting this error PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):

Comment: so you can google for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock

Comment: I am using shared hosting