# mysqli Could not connect

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have this site. And I want to edit a div based on some database data.

I found out that a fairly easy solution would be to connect with `mysqli("servername", "username", "password", "database")`.

Problem is, I can't connect to the database

I think it has to do with what I should input to the `servername` `username` and `password` fields.

I have tried for the servername:

- localhost
- damon.multiserver.gr (which is the hostname of the myphp database)
- I also performed nslookup to damon.multiserver.gr and used that ip
- the site's url

for the username:

- root
- created new user with desired permissions

for the password:

- ""
- the password from the user I created

The database elements are in multiple languages, including Greek.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "", "grcrenta_2020");
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    exit('Could not connect');
}
...more code
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried outputting `$mysqli->connect_error` to see what it actually says? It's easier to debug if you check the real error message instead of hiding it behind a custom one.

Comment: It says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: There are multiple possible problems.
1) For your localhost connection: root login is disabled on MySQL server
2) On your remote DB: The user was created using 'user'@'localhost'. This restricts the user to only be able to connect from the same server. Use 'user'@'%' to enable remote access
3) The port on the remote server isn't opened.

Comment: Have you tried using the actual root password, the one you created when you installed mysql

Comment: @stui - lol, yes , but I can certify the port is open on that host.

Comment: read all about granting privileges to a user : many places you can find this, like [here](https://linuxhint.com/create-new-user-mysql/). Also, dunno what that host is, but opening 3306 on the internets of hacks is a bad idea.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60668665/12232340

Comment: @NIKOLAOSILIOPOULOS which mysql version you are using?

Comment: @NIKOLAOSILIOPOULOS Please [edit] your question to include a description how exactly you have created the users to your database. There might be a simple issue with `FLUSH PRIVILIGES`. Also include the result of `SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user`. Also describe how you can connect to your database outside of your PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$mysqli -> new mysqli(host, username, password, dbname, port, socket);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "grcrenta_2020",3306);
```

Comment: What did you change? What should we try?